# Drawing/sketches in blender

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty new to 3d modelling and have been working through a lot of tutorials. Something I see come up often is users importing sketches of objects such as people, the then seem to create the model around these front, top and side view sketches.

Would anyone be able to link me to a tutorial explaining this feature and its benfits, tricks, how to do it properly?

Sorry if this thread already exists. I couldn't find one

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could follow this
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Modeling_a_Wolf_from_Guide_Images, keeping this in mind https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Background_Images

It seems suited to a beginner, to me.

My personal advice: the most precise (all views well aligned, same scale, absolutely still subject) front/side/top view you can get, the better.

Comment: Please avoid giving link-only answers as if the link goes down then so does this answer. If you can, include some of the steps in the body of this answer.

Comment: I did what the poster asked: he wished to be "linked" to a tutorial

Comment: It's a general guideline on this site (that you weren't to know) that we don't only post links, regardless of whether that is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Ok I will do that from now on. Is there a place with "general guidelines" so that I can read and stick to other ones? And, if the OP asks for a tutorial, and there are already plenty of them but I can't just link them, should the question be rejected as inappropriate or should I replicate the best tutorial I can find as an answer...? :D

Comment: @m.ardito http://blender.stackexchange.com/help and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As @cegaton mentioned, the help section is probably best, along with the site meta where discussions about the site occur: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/ . Requests for tutorials are generally off-topic as questions should be specific enough that an entire tutorial isn't required as an answer: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/311/241